# Does it make sense to restrict from where a user can connect to a RDS, if already using a DB security group?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Since *AWS' RDS* have a firewall based on EC2 security groups (or IP ranges), is it meaningful at all to also restrict connections' origins by restricting users?

Comment: how did you go with this? do you need further help with this?

Comment: thanks @DrewKhoury, I think I'm going to follow the safest way and do both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a good idea to do both.**

While you might think,

> I've secured the stack via AWS security groups, there's no point in
>   doing it again at the application level.

...here are a few things to consider:

- AWS might experience a bug or vulnerability which permits access where it shouldn't
- You might accidentally remove or change a security group rule
- You want broad rules at the security group level, but more specific rules per mysql user

You might consider restricting access at the mysql level overkill, and too much of a maintenance burden. At the end of the day it's up to you decide if the added security is worth the extra work.